# HTML5/CSS overflow on dropdowns

Tags: css, html

I'm building this website as part of college project, I have built my navigation drop downs but there is a kind of over flow on the left of the list items that I can't seem to get rid of. I have tried playing around with the widths and overflow but I just can't seem to get rid of it without messing up the functionality of my dropdown, any help would be greatly appreciated.

wont let me post an image but here is a link: http://postimg.org/image/q4uo0sjfp/

**This is the CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
html {background:none;}

table{
    width:100%;
}

table, th, td {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    padding: none;
    align: center;

}


.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

.cf {
    zoom:1;
}

body {
    font: 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background: 8BA0BB;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}


h1, h2, h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    color: #174D92;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 4.4em;
    font:100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#174D92;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header{
    position:fixed; 
    width:100%; 
    height:206px;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index:999;
    }

header img{
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    float:left;
}

nav {
    height: 3.1em;
    width:100%;
    background:#174D92;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
    z-index:999;
}

div {
    background:#7FB7FF;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #174D92;
    Border-radius:25px;
    Padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.insurers a img{
    border: 1px solid #174D92;}

.insurers a:hover img{
    border: 3px solid #174D92;
    opacity:0.4;
}

div.textsmall{font-size: 85%}


ul, li {
    float:left; 
    padding:none;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;

    }

ul {
background: #7FB7FF;
width:97.6%;
height:2.9em;
text-align: center;
vertical-align:central;
margin-top:.1em;


}

li { 
position:relative;
}


li a {
display:block;
width: auto;
padding:none;
line-height:2.9em;
text-decoration:none;
color: #174D92;

}

li a:hover, .topmenu > li:hover > a{
    background:#174D92;
    color: #7FB7FF;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;

}

ul.topmenu{text-align:center;
}

ul.submenu {
background:#7FB7FF;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
float:none;
position:absolute;
top:2.9em;
left:10000em;
max-height: 0;
transition:max-height 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:999;
}

ul.submenu li {
    padding: none;
    float: none;
    color: #174D92;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index:999;
}

ul.topmenu li:hover ul{
    Left:-40px;
    max-height: 30em;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.submenu li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8D8F92;
    border-right: 0;
    line-height:3em;
    padding: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.submenu li a:hover {
    background:#174D92;
    color:#7FB7FF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

ul.submenu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}

ul.submenu li:first-child a {
    padding: none;
}

.fadein { position:relative; width: auto; height: 545px; margin-top: 1em;}

.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; border-radius:25px; border: 4px solid #174D92;}

iframe{
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #174D92;
}

.divtext{
    width:60%;
    text-align:center;
}
.aligncent{
    align-content:center;
    text-align:center;
}



.blank{
    background:none;
    border:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Physio Central Dublin</title>
</head>
<div class="wrapper blank" style="height:auto; width:100%">
<header><img src="headerimg.png"></header>
</div>
<body>
<nav class="cf">
<ul class="topmenu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Treatments.html" title="Treatments" class="current">Treatments</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#physio" title="Physiotherapy" class="current">Physiotherapy</a></li>
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#acupuncture" title="Acupuncture" class="current">Acupuncture</a></li>
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#sports" title="Sports Injury" class="current">Sports Injury</a></li>
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#osteopathy" title="Osteopathy" class="current">Osteopathy</a></li>
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#exercise" title="Exercise Therapy" class="current">Exercise Therapy</a></li>
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#massage" title="Massage Therapy" class="current">Massage Therapy</a></li>
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#orthotics" title="Orthotics" class="current">Orthotics</a></li>
    <li><a href="Treatments.html#dryneed" title="Dry Needling" class="current">Dry Needling</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="Pricing.html" title="Pricing" class="current">Pricing</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="Pricing.html" title="Pricing For Sessions" class="current">Pricing for sessions</a></li>
    <li><a href="Pricing.html" title="Are you covered" class="current">Are you covered</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="About Us.html" title="Physiotherapy" class="current">About Us</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="About Us.html" title="About Physio Central" class="current">About Physio Central</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact us.html" title="Opening Times" class="current">Opening Times</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact us.html" title="Location" class="current">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Us.html" title="Our People" class="current">Our People</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact us.html" title="Contact Us" class="current">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Testimonies.htm" title="Testimonies" class="current">Testimonies</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="FAQ.html" title="FAQ" class="current">FAQ</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="FAQ.html" title="FAQ" class="current">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle for it if you can, much easier to tinker with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to tell the `ul` to have zero padding.

```
ul.submenu {
  background:#7FB7FF;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  transition:max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:999;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

If you remove the absolute positioning as well then it will drop directly below your menu item, which I assume is what you was after as well.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, thanks a million, been messing with it for days trying to figure it out.

Comment: haha always the way, sometimes it just takes fresh eyes! Don't think to mark the question answered etc.